##[error]Error: Secrets cannot contain multiple lines - task: npmAuthenticate@0
We have a pipeline that has the task type: npmAuthenticate@0, which when executed shows the following error: ##[error]Error: Secrets cannot contain multiple lines.
The service connection assigned in the "customEndpoint" property is of type NPM. It started to fail today 06-20-2024 from 10:00 GTM-5.
Does anyone else have the same problem?

We created a new service connection, but the problem persists.

Have you tried scrubbing the secrets of hidden "\n\r" and re adding?

Yes, and I put the written value, not copied and continued with the problem. The strange thing is that it was working normally, and currently the error began to appear

I tested the npmAuthenticate@0 task in pipeline, and I found it works in my pipeline. I set the "customEndpoint" property with my NPM service connection.
After comparing my log with your screenshot, I found my task version is 0.238.2, and yours is 0.241.1. The update of the task was merged last week and it seems that the updated version has not yet been applied to all organizations.

Considering that your task was successful before, it is likely that the problem is caused by the task version update.
You can check whether the task version of your previous successful runs is version 0.238.2. If so, you can temporarily specify to use the old version of the task as a workaround until the issue is fixed.
          - task: npmAuthenticate@0.238.2
            inputs:
              workingFile: '.npmrc'
              customEndpoint: 'NPM service connection'



Can confirm locking the task to 0.238.2 is working for us in the interim.

Same problem here. It was working fine until 18/06 and stopped woking yesterday.
I'll try specifying the version.
Edit¹ More info:
18/06:

20/06:

Edit² after test:
After downgrading the task version The task succeded.
Thank you!
